# 14.04 desktop ldap login

Tags: 14.04, login, ldap

Quick question with 14.04, I cant get the prompt to allow LDAP logins, on the login screen.

Before 14.04, I used to run:

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -m true
```

which allows me to type in usernames, but this file no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

I got this going by creating a file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-manlogin.conf with the following:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

i got this procedure from here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM

Answer (score 2):

The file you're looking for in Ubuntu 14.04 is located here:

```
/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
```

Then using the suggested

```
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

works as expected.